# Live Location Tracking in app termination state

Tags: flutter, location, background-process

I am developing a food delivery app which requires to implement live location tracking for the rider's location even when the rider has closed the app. I am currently using Flutter for the app development and Firebase for the backend.

How can I improve the location tracking functionality in my Flutter app beyond using the [background_locator_2](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator_2) package, which stores location data to a file in the mobile phone's temporary directory and provides callbacks for storing location data to Firebase?

I am seeking a more efficient approach that eliminates the need for file handling while still providing similar functionality to the background_locator_2 package. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Jawad, did you find anything new to your issue?
I'm facing the same issue now :(

Comment: Have't found any solution yet.